# Use default menu links in multilingual site

Tags: 8

I have a Drupal 8 site with Greek and English installed, where Greek is the main language. I have only translated some of the pages in English.

I have a flag to change the language in these translated pages, but when you see the English version, you also see the Greek menu. Instead of the original links in the menu, you see the auto translated nodes that have been created.

I want to use the default Greek menu. When I click on menu links, I want that link to take to the Greek page, not English.

I have searched enough, but everyone has the opposite problem and cannot create a new menu. I just want to use the same, with the same URLs.

Comment: What are you multilingual settings for that menu? Have you tried setting it to be not translatable?

Comment: I actually can not find that option. I only see "translate". If i don't translate it just creates a node with the same content as in my greek page.

Comment: There are many things that can be translated independently from each other. The entire menu can be translatable or not translatable, each menu item can be assigned a language or not, content nodes can be assigned a language, a translation, or keep them undefined. I am talking about the multilingual settings for the entire Menu, check the `Menu language` setting when you edit the entire menu (Structure > Menus). Also please clarify your question, what do you mean "flag", Flag is a module in Drupal, but that's not what you meant?